# How to store a double and Integer in a list?

Tags: java

I am trying to store a different types such a double and integers inside a list. Can someone give me an example on how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Is converting the integers to doubles an option? That would be a simple solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can store a `List<Number>` and store a `Double` and an `Integer`

However this can  be needlessly complicated to work with as every `int` can be stored as a double without loss.

This means you can use a `List<Double>`  with is simple but not as efficient as TDoubleArrayList which keeps the values as primitives save quite a bit of memory and GC if you have lots of these.

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1.234); // a double
list.add(1.0);   // a double
list.add((double) 1); // an int.

for(Double d: list)
    System.out.println(d);
```

Using TDoubleArrayList

```
TDoubleArrayList list = new TDoubleArrayList();
list.add(1.234); // a double
list.add(1.0);   // a double
list.add(1); // an int.

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
   System.out.println(list.get(i));
```

Comment: What is `TDoubleArrayList`? I don't find such a class.

Comment: @Lion http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TDoubleArrayL ist.html To find it you need google.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Number> list = new ArrayList<Number>();
list.add(new Integer());
list.add(new Double());

if(list.get(0) instanceof Integer){
  Integer i = (Integer)list.get(0);
} else {
  Double d = (Double)list.get(0);
}
```

Comment: This works fine, but the missing question is how do I get the values out again. ;)

Comment: Casting to a Type after checking the instance of the Type.

Comment: would recommend to use `Number` instead of `Object`

Comment: +1 for adding the getting code. It's not trivial for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) class for example. A better option would be to cast your Integer to Double values.

Comment: You can't cast an `Integer` to a `Double` but you can call `doubleValue()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
List<Number> list = new ArrayList<Number>();
list.add(new Double(0.01));
list.add(new Integer(1));
```